# What is the list of available callbacks for ActionCable subscription create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I am trying to setup my Rails 5 `ActionCable` for broadcasting updates to my database. So far I got things going but I realized that the documentation on ActionCable is kind of lacking. For my case, I want to know the list of callback I am allowed to put into the function `subscriptions.create()`.

For example

```
const consumer = ActionCable.createConsumer();
consumer.subscriptions.create(
    'ChatsChannel'
    {
        received: someCallback,
        connected: otherCallback,
        disconnected: anotherCallback
    }
 )
```

I noticed that there are `appendLine` and `createLine` from

section 5.4 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html

How many more are there? What do they correspond to? This is so different from the usual websocket on Node.js and Python. Using socket.io, I only get 4 options, `open`, `close`, `error` and `message`. Why does `ActionCable` seem so *unconventional* when Rails is supposed to be convention over configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from the source code, those are the only three callbacks made available out of the box:

[connected](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable/connection.coffee#L95)

[received](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable/connection.coffee#L99)

[disconnected](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-2-stable/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable/connection.coffee#L113)

Answer (score 0):

In the section you point in the [guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html#passing-parameters-to-channels):

```
# app/assets/javascripts/cable/subscriptions/chat.coffee
App.cable.subscriptions.create { channel: "ChatChannel", room: "Best Room" },
  received: (data) ->
    @appendLine(data)

  appendLine: (data) ->
    html = @createLine(data)
    $("[data-chat-room='Best Room']").append(html)

  createLine: (data) ->
    """
    <article class="chat-line">
      <span class="speaker">#{data["sent_by"]}</span>
      <span class="body">#{data["body"]}</span>
    </article>
    """
```

In this code `appendLine` and `createLine` are just callbacks defined there, pointed by `@appendLine` and `@createLine`, respectively. It's just CoffeeScript syntax to module more expressively your code.

> How many more are there?

Honestly, I'm not sure. I haven't find any JS documentation as extensive as the one for [the ruby documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionCable/Channel/Base.html) of Action cable. But `appendLine` and `createLine` are NOT defined callbacks, they appear only in that example.

// UPDATE:

The complete list can be found [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actioncable/app/assets/javascripts/action_cable/subscription.coffee).

Comment: This does not even make an attempt to answer this question.